# Terminology: Python and Numpy - `iterable` versus `array_like`

Tags: python, numpy

What is the difference between an `iterable` and an `array_like` object in Python programs which use `Numpy`?

Both `iterable` and `array_like` are often seen in Python documentation and they share some similar properties.

I understand that in this context an `array_like` object should support `Numpy` type operations like broadcasting, however `Numpy` arrays area also iterable.  Is it correct to say that `array_like` is an extension (or super-set?) of `iterable`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The term ["array-like"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html#converting-python-array-like-objects-to-numpy-arrays) is indeed only used in NumPy and refers to anything that can be passed as first parameter to `numpy.array()` to create an array.

The term ["iterable"](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable) is standard python terminology and refers to anything that can be iterated over (for example using `for x in iterable`).

Most array-like objects are iterable, with the exception of scalar types.

Many iterables are not array-like -- for example you can't construct a NumPy array from a generator expression using `numpy.array()`.  (You would have to use `numpy.fromiter()` instead.  Nonetheless, a generator expression isn't an "array-like" in the terminology of the NumPy documentation.)

Comment: Great - thanks.  That clears it up, especially the link between `array-like` and the first arg of `numpy.array()`.

Comment: "All array-like objects are iterable" - this is not correct. Scalar value of ```int``` type is array-like and can be passed to ```numpy.array()```, but it is not iterable.

Comment: @wombatonfire Yup, that's true.  Even actual 0-d arrays can't be iterated, while they are clearly "array-like".  They are even arrays.

Answer (score 5):

While the first part of the Sven's answer is correct, I would like to add that array-like objects should not necessarily be iterable.

For example, in my particular situation I was interested in using `numpy.rint()` function that accepts array-like objects with scalars of type `int`. They are not iterable, but they are accepted. You can also pass `int`s to `numpy.array()`, so they **are** array-like.

Here is the confirmation from the "NumPy-Discussion" mailing list: https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2016-November/076224.html