# numpy all differing from builtin all

Tags: python, numpy

What is the reason for this weirdness in numpy's `all`?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.all(xrange(10))
False
>>> np.all(i for i in xrange(10))
True
```

Comment: `np.__version__` is 1.6.2

Comment: You can read [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/numpy/RRvH2NgR3Ik) for some of the back-and-forth.  I come down on the throw-an-exception side.

Comment: related:  http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg06476.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numpy.all does not understands generator expressions.

From the documentation

```
 numpy.all(a, axis=None, out=None)

    Test whether all array elements along a given axis evaluate to True.
    Parameters :    

    a : array_like

        Input array or object that can be converted to an array.
```

Ok, not very explicit, so lets look at the code

```
def all(a,axis=None, out=None):
    try:
        all = a.all
    except AttributeError:
        return _wrapit(a, 'all', axis, out)
    return all(axis, out)

def _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    try:
        wrap = obj.__array_wrap__
    except AttributeError:
        wrap = None
    result = getattr(asarray(obj),method)(*args, **kwds)
    if wrap:
        if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):
            result = asarray(result)
        result = wrap(result)
    return result
```

As generator expression doesn't have `all` method, it ends up calling `_wrapit`
In `_wrapit`, it first checks for `__array_wrap__` method which `generates AttributeError` finally ending up calling `asarray` on the generator expression

From the documentation of `numpy.asarray`

```
 numpy.asarray(a, dtype=None, order=None)

    Convert the input to an array.
    Parameters :    

    a : array_like

        Input data, in any form that can be converted to an array. This includes lists, lists of tuples, tuples, tuples of tuples, tuples of lists and ndarrays.
```

It is well documented about the various types of Input data thats accepted which is definitely not generator expression

Finally, trying

```
>>> np.asarray(0 for i in range(10))
array(<generator object <genexpr> at 0x42740828>, dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange.  When I try that I get:

```
>>> np.all(i for i in xrange(10))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f6e04c64500>
```

Hmm.

I don't think [numpy understands generator expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8217068/17875).  Try using a list comprehension and you get this:

```
>>> np.all([i for i in xrange(10)])
False
```