# All command in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I use the **all** command in Python to execute something if all entries satisfy a constraint. For example, here I check if all entries are positive and print the no. of negative numbers if all are positive. So ideally you would expect to print output of 3 if all numbers are positive and none if one of the numbers is negative. However I get the value 2 as output. Why's it so?

```
 if all(x>0 for x in array([-10,1,2])):
     print sum(x>0 for x in array([-10,1,2]))
```

[image]

Comment: What does `array()` do?

Comment: On my machine, your code doesn't print anything. So IMHO this works as intended...

Comment: Same here once I removed the call to `array()`. It's possible whatever that function is returning is satisfying the conditions for the statement to evaluate to `True`.

Comment: *"print the no. of negative numbers if all are positive"*? Wat.

Comment: @Matt: Sorry, a typo. I expect a 3 or nothing for this code, but I get a 2.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Typo, please check now.

Comment: Um, you didn't change that. And you really should answer the question of @IanAuld

Comment: I suppose he did `from numpy import *` or `from scipy import *` so probably `array` will produce a numpy array...

Comment: With or without numpy/scipy, `-10` means that the `all(x>0 ...)` statement is false, and therefore won't print anything.

Comment: "*if all entries are positive and print the no. of negative numbers if all are positive*"... You'll have 0 negative numbers if all are positive (depending on whether you count 0 itself as positive, I suppose). Assuming this was a typo, the number of positive numbers will be the length of the array (assuming 1d array). `sum` probably isn't the right way to go about this. Could you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clearer you're using Numpy, I'll use an explicit import instead if `from numpy import *`:

```
import numpy as np
if np.all(x>0 for x in np.array([-10,1,2])):
    print np.sum(x>0 for x in np.array([-10,1,2]))
```

Here, `x>0 for x in np.array([-10,1,2])` is a generator, and [`numpy.all` doesn't work on generators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16334860/372643).

In addition, you might be interested in filtering arrays, to achieve what you want, using `> 0` on the array directly as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a1 = np.array([-10,1,2])
>>> a2 = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a1 > 0
array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> a2 > 0
array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> np.all(a1 > 0)
False
>>> np.all(a2 > 0)
True
```

You may be interested in this: [Boolean or “mask” index arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays)

You'll find more about the behaviour of `numpy.all` and generators in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14392453/372643).

---

Regarding your secondary question (why 2 instead of 3), it's because `np.sum` treats `True` as 1 and `False` as 0, once you've passed the test condition. It's more visible if you expand the generator as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> g = (x>0 for x in array([-10,1,2]))
>>> g
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f0edfc3b640>
>>> l = list(g)
>>> l
[False, True, True]
>>> np.sum(l)
2
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno. This comes closest to what I want. However, if it does not work on generators, why does the statement evaluate to a TRUE and the print command executed?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14392453/372643) might give you a better explanation. That would certainly reinforce the suggestion that it's not a good idea to use `from numpy import *` (or generally `from ... import *`), so as not to make `numpy.all` collide with Python's native `all`. It just makes the code harder to read and leads to different behaviours.

Comment: Excellent. Now I see the issue here. Good lesson learnt on import. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got what you mean. If you enter the `if` statement (means that the condition was evaluated `True`) than it must result in 3 (because the number of positives - where `x > 0` would be all of the three). Agreed.

But, in this situation, you don't even enter the `if` statement because the condition is evaluated `False` as the when comprehending a list the following way:

```
a = [x > 0 for x in array([-10, 2, 1])]
```

You should get `[False, True, True]` which when called as an argument to `all()` will result in `False`. Therefore, you won't even print anything. Maybe you're confusing and you're printing something somewhere else.

Either way, doesn't print anything on my system - as it shouldn't.

Comment: It is surprising. I have attached the screenshot of my window. It does print 2.

Comment: @Bravo It's not so surprising: `[x > 0 for x in array([-10, 2, 1])]` and `(x > 0 for x in array([-10, 2, 1]))` (or what's without parentheses within your `all(...)`) are not the same: the former is a list, the latter is a generator.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in array([-10,1,2]) 
I use range instead and work well

```
if all(x > 0 for x in range(-10, 1, 2)):
    print(    sum(x > 0 for x in range(-10, 1, 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a reason for using `array` and not a plain list. It's used like this, however (assuming `from array import array`):

```
array('i', [-10, 1, 2])
```

Where 'i' indicates this is an array of signed integers.

Regardless of whether you use the above or a plain old list, you had a correct way of counting the number of positive values. `all()`, as mentioned in another answer will result in `False` when any value in the list is `False`, which makes your original code never enter the `if` block, but it's completely superfluous here. If you only want to count the number of positive values, you can just go with your second line:

```
sum(x > 0 for x in array('i', [-10, 1, 2]))
```

(With the proper use of `array`, of course.)