# What is Python's sequence protocol?

Tags: python, sequence, cpython, python-internals

Python does a lot with magic methods and most of these are part of some protocol. I am familiar with the "iterator protocol" and the "number protocol" but recently stumbled over the term ["sequence protocol"](https://docs.python.org/c-api/sequence.html#sequence-protocol). But even after some research I'm not exactly sure what the "sequence protocol" is.

For example the C API function [`PySequence_Check`](https://docs.python.org/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Check) checks (according to the documentation) if some object implements the "sequence protocol". The [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/813f943c592cf225871b99cffc99304c8cbbee40/Objects/abstract.c#L1471) indicates that this is a class that's not a dict but implements a `__getitem__` method which is *roughly* identical to what the documentation on [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) also states:

> [...]must support the sequence protocol (the `__getitem__()` method with integer arguments starting at 0).[...]

But the requirement to start with `0` isn't something that's "implemented" in `PySequence_Check`.

Then there is also the [`collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) type, which basically says the instance has to implement `__reversed__`, `__contains__`, `__iter__` and `__len__`.

But by that definition a class implementing the "sequence protocol" isn't necessarily a Sequence, for example the ["data model"](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) and the abstract class guarantee that a sequence has a length. But a class just implementing `__getitem__` (passing the `PySequence_Check`) throws an exception when using `len(an_instance_of_that_class)`.

Could someone please clarify for me the difference between a sequence and the sequence protocol (if there's a definition for the protocol besides reading the source code) and when to use which definition?

Comment: `collections.abc.Sequence` requires `__getitem__` and `__len__`. There are mixin methods for everything else. Regarding iteration, if just `__getitem__` is defined without an `__iter__`, then built-in `iter` instantiates a simple iterator that starts at index 0. For `reversed` to work `__len__` also has to be defined, so it can start at the last index.

Comment: @eryksun But a class doesn't need a `__len__` to implement the sequence protocol (as far as `PySequence_Check` is concerned). And a class implementing `__len__` and `__getitem__` but not inheriting from `collections.abc.Sequence` isn't passing `isinstance(an_instance, Sequence)`. That is what triggered my question. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not really consistent.

Here's [`PySequence_Check`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/abstract.c#L1460):

```
int
PySequence_Check(PyObject *s)
{
    if (PyDict_Check(s))
        return 0;
    return s != NULL && s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence &&
        s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_item != NULL;
}
```

`PySequence_Check` checks if an object provides the C sequence protocol, implemented through a `tp_as_sequence` member in the `PyTypeObject` representing the object's type. This `tp_as_sequence` member is a pointer to a struct containing a bunch of functions for sequence behavior, such as `sq_item` for item retrieval by numeric index and `sq_ass_item` for item assignment.

Specifically, `PySequence_Check` requires that its argument is not a dict, and that it provides `sq_item`.

Types with a `__getitem__` written in Python will provide `sq_item` regardless of whether they're conceptually sequences or mappings, so a mapping written in Python that doesn't inherit from `dict` will pass `PySequence_Check`.

---

On the other hand, `collections.abc.Sequence` only checks whether an object concretely inherits from `collections.abc.Sequence` or whether its class (or a superclass) is explicitly `register`ed with `collections.abc.Sequence`. If you just implement a sequence yourself without doing either of those things, it won't pass `isinstance(your_sequence, Sequence)`. Also, most classes registered with `collections.abc.Sequence` don't support all of `collections.abc.Sequence`'s methods. Overall, `collections.abc.Sequence` is a lot less reliable than people commonly expect it to be.

---

As for what counts as a sequence in practice, it's usually anything that supports `__len__` and `__getitem__` with integer indexes starting at 0 and isn't a mapping. If the docs for a function say it takes any sequence, that's almost always all it needs. Unfortunately, "isn't a mapping" is hard to test for, for reasons similar to how "is a sequence" is hard to pin down.

Comment: I think `PySequence_Check` excludes `dict`s because subclasses could implement `__getitem__`, as for custom classes they do return `True` when they implement `__getitem__`: https://gist.github.com/MSeifert04/e39d91f9d262618a32f7db14aaab15f4. Thank you for the answer (especially for pointing out that `collections.abc.Sequence` doesn't have a `__subclasshook__` was new to me), I'll leave it unaccepted for another day in case someone else wants to provide an answer.

Comment: @MSeifert: Yeah, I was wrong about user-defined classes and `sq_item`. I could've sworn there wasn't handling to provide `sq_item` by wrapping `__getitem__`, but apparently there is, and it's not new.

Comment: See [issue 23864](http://bugs.python.org/issue23864) regarding the limitations for `issubclass` with the ABCs that aren't "one-trick ponies". It's always seemed needlessly limited to me.

Comment: @eryksun I have asked Guido if he can add the missing `__subclasshook__` in your issue as it is still open. By the way, do you know why the table of [Collections Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.abc.html) is missing some abstract of mixin methods (for instances, the class `Reversible` is missing the mixin method `__iter__` and the class `Coroutine` is missing the abstract method `__await__`)?

Comment: @Maggyero: Those are both inherited abstract methods. `Reversible` inherits `__iter__` from `Iterable`, and `Coroutine` inherits `__await__` from `Awaitable`. (Also, `__iter__` isn't a mixin method because implementing `__iter__` in terms of `__reversed__` would be inefficient and bizarre.)

Comment: @user2357112 Okay, but why aren't these inherited abstract methods listed in the column _Abstract Methods_ of the `Reversible` and `Coroutine` classes (contrary to the inherited abstract methods of the `Collection` class for instance which are listed)?

Answer (score 0):

For a type to be in accordance with the sequence protocol, these 4 conditions must be met:

- Retrieve elements by index

  `item = seq[index]`
- Find items by value

  `index = seq.index(item)`
- Count items

  `num = seq.count(item)`
- Produce a reversed sequence

  `r = reversed(seq)`

Comment: Could you link the source of this info or explain how you know this?

Comment: I agree it would be prudent to provide the source of this information.