# How to put a textbox into a python tkinter application?

Tags: python, search, tkinter, textbox, tkinter-entry

I've looked at several other questions and none of them seem to help with my solution. I think I'm just not very intelligent sadly.

Basic question I know. I decided to learn python and I'm making a basic app with tkinter to learn.

Basically it's an app that stores and displays people's driving licence details (name and expiry date). One of the abilities I want it to have is a name lookup. To begin with, I need to figure out how to put a textbox into my window!

I will post the relevant (well, what I think is relevant!) code below:

```
class search(tk.Frame):


def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter a name to display that individual's details", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)     

    label1 = tk.Label(console, text="Name:").pack()
    searchbox = tk.Entry(console)
    searchbox.pack()


    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="SEARCH", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(main))#not created yet
    button1.pack()

    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="HOME", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(main))
    button2.pack()
```

and of course at the top I have

```
import tkinter as tk
```

When I try and run this I get "typeobject "search" has no attribute 'tk'". It worked fine - the search window would open when I click the relevant button on the home window. Until I tried to add the Entry box.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm an utter newbie so I'm prepared to face my stupidity

Also apologies if the formatting of this question is awful, I'm a newbie posting here as well. Putting everything into correct "code" format is a real pain

Comment: Oh and the indentation below the class is correct in the script, it's just a pain to do on here

Comment: It's not a pain to do here. It takes just a few seconds. Please take the time to fix it. Move the line with "class" all the way to the left. Select all the code. Click the button that looks like `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're running into problems since you didn't specify a layout manager and passed `console` instead of `self`:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Search(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, controller=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.pack()  # specify layout manager

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Enter a name to display that individual's details")
        label1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Name:")
        label2.pack()

        searchbox = tk.Entry(self)
        searchbox.pack()

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="SEARCH", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(main))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="HOME", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(main))
        button2.pack()

# Just cobble up the rest for example purposes:

main = None

class Controller:
    def show_frame(self, frame=None):
        pass

app = Search(controller=Controller())
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, using `from tkinter import *` is a more efficient way of importing Tkinters libraries without having to import specific things when needed.  To answer your question though, here is the code for entering a text box.
`t1 = Text(self)`

To insert text into the text box: `t1.insert()`

An example of this would be `t1.insert(END, 'This is text')`

If you haven't got it already, t1 is the variable I'm assigning to the text box, although you can choose whatever variable you want.  I highly recommend effbots tutorial on tkinter, I found it extremely useful.  Here is the link:  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-application-windows.htm

Best of luck!

Comment: `from ... import *` is considered bad style (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)  and often leads to confusion, especilly amongst beginners (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502124/on-import-modules-and-method-names-in-python).

Comment: Good point Hannebambel, but considering all of tkinter is strictly gui related, it would save time instead of importing specific items.

Comment: using `import tkinter as tk` is the preferred method as it allows for better comparability between versions of tkinter by reducing the needed changes to the code between versions.

Comment: also if you use `import tkinter as tk` you prevent any overlapping imports with other libraries.