# What does "array-like" mean in the sklearn documentation?

Tags: python, arrays

The term "array-like" appears all over the sklearn documentation, and what that means is reasonably well defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/numpy-formal-definition-of-array-like-objects).

I have a situation where I have a dataset that will not fit in memory, but can be reasonably easily generated on-demand.  As such, I would like to implement an "array-like" class that generates my data.  However, it is not entirely clear what operations I should implement to make this work.  Presumably I need `__getitem__`.  Possibly also `next` and `__iter__`.  How does one create an "array-like" class in python?

Comment: What you need are Python's generators. They `yield` one element at a time.

Comment: they are not array-like, because they are not random access

Comment: I would be able to write an appropriate class.  Mostly, I will need to pass this thing to a `.fit` method, and not have my computer explode.

Comment: It looks like the source in most sklearn methods call `check_array` which does an `ndarray` conversion.  This is going to be harder than I thought...