# Sorting array using indices results in too many indices for array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm attempting to sort a dictionaries keys according to its values. So I have used numpy's `argsort` to sort the values in ascending order. But when I attempt to sort the keys according to the values indices I get the error:

> IndexError: too many indices for array

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import numpy as np

## Map occurences of colours in image
colour_map = {}
#...
colour_map['#fff'] = 15
colour_map['#ccc'] = 99
#...

## Sort colour map from most frequent to least 
colours         = np.array(colour_map.keys())   # dict_keys(['#fff', '#ccc'])
col_frequencies = np.array(colour_map.values()) # dict_values([15, 99])

indicies = col_frequencies.argsort()

# Error on below line "IndexError: too many indices for array"
colours = colours[indicies[::-1]]
```

Comment: When you call `.keys()`  and `values()` numpy doesn't convert them to char or integer arrays but instead object arrays. `colours         = np.array(list(colour_map.keys()))` followed by `col_frequencies = np.array(list(colour_map.values()))` should solve this.

Comment: @ayhan Thanks that fixed it. If you make an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Your code works fine as-is on `Python 2.7.12` with `Numpy 1.13.0`.

Comment: @carthurs doesn't work in Python 3.6

Comment: @JakeM I still couldn't figure out why `colours[0]` raises an error. It's an array with a single item after all. Maybe someone can come up with an explanation.

Comment: @JakeM It seems the return type of dict.keys() changed between Python 2 and 3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python

Comment: @ayhan I investigated this, and it turns out it's not an array with a single item - see my answer below!

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3,
`dir(np.array(colour_map.keys()))` shows that this class not satisfy the `array_like` requirement which is specified as being necessary in the documentation for `numpy.array` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

The definition of `array_like` was explored in more detail here [numpy: formal definition of "array_like" objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/numpy-formal-definition-of-array-like-objects)

It seems that `np.array` doesn't check whether `array_like` is satisfied, and will happily construct a Numpy array from an object which does not satisfy it.

Then when you try to index it, the indexing doesn't work.

Here's an example with `my_object` designed not to be `array_like`.

```
class my_object():
    def greet(self):
        print("hi!")

a = my_object()
a.greet()
print(dir(a))  # no __array__ attribute

b = np.array(a)

b[0]
```

results in

```
hi!
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'greet']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/to/my/script.py", 
line 35, in <module>
    b[0]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Now let's try making it array-like (or at least sufficiently array-like for this to work):

```
class my_object():
    def greet(self):
        print("hi!")

    def __array__(self):
        return np.array([self])

a = my_object()

b = np.array(a)

b[0].greet()  # Now we can index b successfully
```

results in:

```
hi!
```