# How to average several readings in python?

Tags: python, numpy

A sensor generates an reading every one second for five seconds. I was trying to use the function `np.mean` to calculate the average of five sensor readings (i.e., `sensor1_t1` to `sensor1_t5`), however it doesn't work.

Can you please help me on this?

Thanks.

```
sensor1_t1 = BridgeValue(0) * 274.0 - 2.1
sleep(1)
sensor1_t2 = BridgeValue(0) * 274.0 - 2.1
sleep(1)
sensor1_t3 = BridgeValue(0) * 274.0 - 2.1
sleep(1)
sensor1_t4 = BridgeValue(0) * 274.0 - 2.1
sleep(1)
sensor1_t5 = BridgeValue(0) * 274.0 - 2.1
sleep(1)

# my code - not working
#avg_sensor1 = np.mean(sensor1_t1, sensor1_t2, sensor1_t3, sensor1_t4, sensor1_t5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be more easily done using Numpy arrays throughout.  Something like:

```
import numpy as np

N = 5
sensor1 = np.zeros((N,), dtype=float)

for i in range(N):
    sensor1[i] = BridgeValue(0) * 274.0 - 2.1
    sleep(1)

average = np.mean(sensor1)
```

Comment: I was thinking about using np.empty based on what I learned from others. Could you please explain why you are using np.zeros? I am assuming the  (N,) is appending new entries to the array?! Thx.

Comment: `np.zeros((N,)` creates an array of zeros, with length `N`.  (Technically a 1d array.)  Then you modify each value within the loop.  So when `i=1`, you are assigning `BridgeValue(0) * 274.0 - 2.1` to `sensor[1]` (the 2nd entry in the array, because it is 0-indexed).  So, you could use `np.empty` or `np.zeros`; they both function just as placeholders.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass an array-like object to the `a` parameter of [`np.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html).  Try:

```
avg_sensor1 = np.mean([sensor1_t1, sensor1_t2, sensor1_t3, sensor1_t4, sensor1_t5])
```

You're currently passing 5 arguments when you need to pass them as one array-like object.

In other words, the syntax for `np.mean` is:

> `numpy.mean(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None,` ...

The way you currently are calling the function, you're passing 5 positional arguments.  These get interpreted as separate parameters:

- `sensor1_t1` is passed to `a`
- `sensor1_t2` is passed to `axis`
- `sensor1_t3` is passed to `dtype`

...and so on.

Note that the syntax I suggested passes a `list`, which is one of the structures that's considered "array-like."  More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/numpy-formal-definition-of-array-like-objects) if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Because numpy is mainly used with arrays (especially `numpy.ndarray`) `numpy.mean` expects an array as it's first argument. But you don't need to create an `ndarray` you can simply change `np.mean(sensor1_t1, sensor1_t2, sensor1_t3, sensor1_t4, sensor1_t5)` to `np.mean([sensor1_t1, sensor1_t2, sensor1_t3, sensor1_t4, sensor1_t5])` and numpy will take care of the rest.