# How to read Scikit learn documentation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am a bit new to Python and was confused on how to read documentation. In particular, the [Scikit learn documentation for their Logistic Regression classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit) describes a function `fit` with the following parameters:

```
 Parameters:    
X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features)
Training vector, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is the number of features.
y : array-like, shape (n_samples,)
Target vector relative to X.
```

The first part of `X` seems to ask for a dictionary ... and but the shape is a tuple?  I'm confused - what type of input is the function expecting for `X` here?

Comment: It's asking for an array-like object, (so like an `np.array`) or a sparse matrix with a particular shape... those aren't literals, those are just brackets...

Comment: Also that would be a set, not a dictionary, as it lacks a colon.

Comment: Going off @jonrsharpe 's comment, a dictionary would be of the form `{ key: value, ... key:value}`, rather than a set which is `{key, key, ... , key}`.

Comment: If it was expecting a `dict` or a `set` it would say "dict" or "set" or "tuple" or whatever.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In Java terms, would that be similar to an ArrayList where each item in the list is a sample feature vector? And thanks everyone for the clarification.

Comment: @Mike No, it would *not* be like an ArrayList.  The term "array-like" in scipy-parlance is defined a bit tautologically, it's anything that can be converted into a `numpy.ndarray`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/numpy-formal-definition-of-array-like-objects). Basically, though, it wants a two-dimensional numpy array.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How do I figure out what should be the array's rows and columns? Is that defined by shape (n_samples, n_features)?

Comment: @Mike yes, exactly. rows are samples, columns are features.