# Why numpy can save and load objects different than numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to make another point and accidentally saved a `dict` using numpy `np.save()`. To my surprise there seem to be no problem at all with that approach. I tried the above with another object that it's not `np.array` like a `list` and it seem to work fine.

For example the following code, saves and loads an object using `np.save()` and `np.load()`:

```
list_file = 'random_list.npy'
random_list = [x*2 for x in range(20)]
np.save(list_file, random_list)

# load numpy array
random_list2 = np.load(list_file)
set(random_list) == set(random_list2)
```

> True

So, my question is:

1. Why is this succeeding anyway since in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) only arrays are mentioned?
2. And similarly if it was meant to deal with other objects, which objects can be handled?

I know there are some limitation regarding pickle which could affect the nature of object that could be handled but a lot of unclear points still exist.

Edit:
I thought that `np.save()` was just trying to convert the object passed as parameter to numpy array but that does not make any sense in some cases like `dict`.

For example a `dict` passed to a np.array does not seem to be functional at all:

```
a = {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2}
b = np.array(a)
type(b)
```

> numpy.ndarray

```
b.shape
```

> ()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`numpy.save()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) documents its argument as *"array-like".*

As per [numpy: formal definition of "array_like" objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/numpy-formal-definition-of-array-like-objects), the underlying [`numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c:PyArray_FromAny()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L1684) accepts:

```
/* op is an array */

/* op is a NumPy scalar */

/* op is a Python scalar */

/* op supports the PEP 3118 buffer interface */

/* op supports the __array_struct__ or __array_interface__ interface */

/* op supplies the __array__ function. */

/* Try to treat op as a list of lists */
```

---

Specifically for `dict`, the execution path goes like this:

[`numpy/npyio.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L449) ->
[`numpy/core/numeric.py:asanyarray()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/numeric.py#L504) ->
[`numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c:_array_fromobject()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c) ->
[`numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c:PyArray_CheckFromAny()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L1794) ->
the aforementioned `PyArray_FromAny`. There:

```
<...>
PyArray_GetArrayParamsFromObject(op, newtype,
                        0, &dtype,
                        &ndim, dims, &arr, context)
<...>
        else {
            if (newtype == NULL) {
                newtype = dtype;    #object dtype
<...>
            ret = (PyArrayObject *)PyArray_NewFromDescr(&PyArray_Type, newtype,
                                         ndim, dims,
                                         NULL, NULL,
                                         flags&NPY_ARRAY_F_CONTIGUOUS, NULL);
    return (PyObject *)ret;
```

Comment: In particular, the function [`np.asanyarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asanyarray.html) is called to convert the argument to a NumPy object. In the case of `dict`s, it will just produce a NumPy scalar with data type `object`.

Comment: A `dict` does not seem to be "array-like" but it's successfully used by numpy in this case though.

Answer (score 3):

A demo:

```
In [507]: np.savez('test', a = [x*2 for x in range(3)], b=dict(a=1,b=np.arange(3)))

In [510]: d = np.load('test.npz')
In [511]: d['a']
Out[511]: array([0, 2, 4])
```

This list was converted to an array and saved.

```
In [512]: d['b']
Out[512]: array({'a': 1, 'b': array([0, 1, 2])}, dtype=object)
In [513]: d['b'].shape
Out[513]: ()
In [514]: d['b'].item()   # or d['b'][()]
Out[514]: {'a': 1, 'b': array([0, 1, 2])}
```

The dictionary was wrapped in a 0d object dtype array, and saved with `pickle`.  The array within the dictionary was `pickled` with `save`.

`np.save` uses pickle where needed to handle non-array objects, and `pickle` uses `save` to handle array objects.