# How do you get the average of each tenth of a list?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm sure there's a numpy function for this, I just haven't found it yet. Say you have a list of integers of arbitrary size. How can you convert this to a list of ten floats, where each float is the average of that tenth of the original list?

Edit: the best I can come up with is to first convert the list to a numpy array, then split it into equal parts using `.array_split(array, 10)`, then take the average of each one. But I imagine there must be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Easier how? You mean easier on yourself or the computer?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could take the mean of several lists at once like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've described is literally a one-liner:

```
np.mean(np.array_split(array, 10), axis=0)
```

`array_split` works on any "array-like", which includes lists, so that "convert the list to a numpy array" is automatic.

`np.mean` also works on any "array-like", which includes the list of arrays returned by `array_split`, treated as a 2D array, so that "… of each one" is also automatic.

So this really is all there is to it.

---

Note that while "array-like" is used all over the NumPy docs, as far as I'm aware, it's never rigorously defined anywhere. But what it basically means is: if you could call `np.array(x)` and get back the array you'd naively hope for, then `x` is array-like. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/) has an answer that delves into the NumPy source to show exactly how array-like values are handled.

Also notice that some NumPy functions don't actually say what types they expect. For example, [`mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) explicitly says it takes an `array_like` for `a`, but [`array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) doesn't say what it takes (and if you tried to guess by following the link to `split`, you'd guess wrong). So, sometimes, the only way to find out of an array-like is acceptable is to test it. But this is a trivial test, so that's not a big deal.

---

Of course if you don't want to use NumPy, you don't have to; it's not *that* much harder to do directly on lists; you just need explicit loops:

```
chunksize = len(array) // 10
chunks = (array[i*chunksize:(i+1)*chunksize] for i in range(10))
means = [statistics.mean(chunk) for chunk in chunks]
```

And of course you can collapse that all into a horrible one-liner if you want to—or, better, wrap the first two lines up in a function that does the same thing as `array_split`, so you can then just do:

```
means = [statistics.mean(chunk) for chunk in my_array_split(array, 10)]
```

… which doesn't look all that different from the NumPy one-liner, it just makes the loop explicit.