# Python - Using string as expression (exec and eval not working)

Tags: python, scipy, eval

I am trying to use `scipy.stats.f_oneway()` to perform ANOVA. It takes `array_like` as input, whatever that means.

[numpy: formal definition of "array_like" objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/numpy-formal-definition-of-array-like-objects)

Anyway, it works when I manually type in the data to be compared. For example, this works:
Input:

```
list1 = [3,4,5,6]
list2 = [4,5,6,7]
list3 = [5,6,7,8]
sp.stats.f_oneway(list1, list2, list3)
```

Output:

```
F_onewayResult(statistic=2.3999, pvalue=0.1461)
```

However, I want to compare a lot of different lists and I would like to compare them dynamically in my code.

This is what I want:

```
list1 = [3,4,5,6]
list2 = [4,5,6,7]
list3 = [5,6,7,8]
listOfLists = [list1, list2, list3]
sp.stats.f_oneway(listOfLists)
```

However, f_oneway does not like this format of input. So I was thinking, maybe I could use a loop to create a string, then unpack it to use as the argument, like this:

```
list1 = [3,4,5,6]
list2 = [4,5,6,7]
list3 = [5,6,7,8]
listString = 'list1, list2, list3'
sp.stats.f_oneway(eval(listString))
```

However, this doesn't work. This leads me to believe this function requires input like:

```
sp.stats.f_oneway(list1, list2, list3)
```

How can I use a string to supply the input required by the f_oneway function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
sp.stats.f_oneway(*listOflists)
```

This will unwrap the list and puts in 3 individual arguments

Comment: Thanks Rocky! I hadn't seen the star operator. Much better than the string way I was thinking.