# Find k nearest neighbors using kd-tree in python when coordinates are held in objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I need to find `k` nearest neighbors for each object from a set. Each object has its coordinates as properties. 
To solve the task, I am trying to use `spatial.KDTree` from `scipy`. It works fine if I use a list or tuple to represent a point, but it doesn't work for objects.
I implemented `__getitem__` and `__len__` methods in my class, but `KDTree` implementation asks my objects for non-existing coordinate axis (say for 3-rd coordinate of 2-dimensional point).

Here is a simple script to reproduce the problem:

```py
from scipy import spatial

class Unit:

    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


    def __getitem__(self, index):        
        if index == 0:
            return self.x
        elif index == 1:
            return self.y
        else:          
            raise Exception('Unit coordinates are 2 dimensional')


    def __len__(self):        
        return 2



#points = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
#points = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]]
points = [Unit(1,1), Unit(2,2), Unit(3,3), Unit(4,4), Unit(5,5)]

tree = spatial.KDTree(points)

#result = tree.query((6,6), 3)
result = tree.query(Unit(6,6), 3)

print(result)
```

It is not necessary for me to use this specific implementation or library or even algorithm, but the requirement is to deal with objects.

P.S. I may add `id` field to each object and move all coordinates into separate array where index is object `id`. But I still want to avoid such approach if possible.

Comment: The data should be array like, according to the docs---presumably, that means not just indexable but also iterable. I believe `__getitem__` and `__len__` make an item iterable, but maybe you need to `raise IndexError` on a bad index, not a generic `Exception`? Presumably it just takes data and tries to convert it to a numpy array. Edit: Yep: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py#L228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) for `scipy.spatial.KDTree` state that the `data` parameter should be `array_like` which generally means "convertible to a numpy array." And indeed, the first line of initialization tries to convert the data to a numpy array, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py#L228):

```py
class KDTree(object):
    """ ... """
    def __init__(self, data, leafsize=10):
        self.data = np.asarray(data)
```

So what you want to achieve is an object so that a list of them converts nicely to a numpy array. This is [hard to exactly define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/numpy-formal-definition-of-array-like-objects) as numpy tries many ways to make your object into an array. However, an iterable containing many sequences of the same length definitely qualifies.

Your `Unit` object is basically a sequence, since it implements `__len__` and `__getitem__` and indexes with sequential integers starting at 0. Python knows when your sequence ends from it hitting an `IndexError`. But your `__getitem__` raises an `Exception` on a bad index instead. So the normal mechanism for providing sequential iteration from those two methods breaks. Instead, raise an `IndexError`, and you'll convert nicely:

```py
class Unit:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __getitem__(self, index):        
        if index == 0:
            return self.x
        elif index == 1:
            return self.y
        raise IndexError('Unit coordinates are 2 dimensional')

    def __len__(self):        
        return 2
```

Now we can check a list of these converts into a numpy array with no problems:

```py
In [5]: np.array([Unit(1, 1), Unit(2, 2), Unit(3, 3), Unit(4, 4), Unit(5, 5)])
Out[5]:
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 5]])
```

So, we should have no problem initializing the `KDTree` now. This is why if you stored the coords in an internal list and just deferred `__getitem__` to that list, or simply treated your coords as some simple sequence like a list or tuple, you'd be fine.

An easier method with simple classes like this would be using `namedtuples` or similar, but for more complex objects, turning them into sequences is a good way to go.

Comment: This is a great answer. What do have in mind using namedtuples? In __getitem__?

Comment: @crypdick namedtuples are tuples, so they are sequences already---no need to define `__getitem__` on them. If you replace the class definition in the above code with `Unit = namedtuple("Unit", "x, y")` then it just works.

Answer (score 1):

The class probably needs to access slices of the object. But with your definition, it is impossible to use a slice (try `Unit(6, 6)[:]`, it will throw the same Error).

One way to deal with this is to hold the x and y variable in a list:

```py
class Unit:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.data = [x, y]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    def __len__(self):        
        return 2

points = [Unit(1,1), Unit(2,2), Unit(3,3), Unit(4,4), Unit(5,5)]
tree = spatial.KDTree(points)
result = tree.query(Unit(6,6), 3)

print(result)
```

```
(array([1.41421356, 2.82842712, 4.24264069]), array([4, 3, 2]))
```