# why np.concatenate() can be used for class 'PIL.Image.Image'?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm reading someone's transform.py, and there is a code which really confuses me. Here it is:

```
np.concatenate(img_group, axis=2)
```

however, the `img_group` here is a sequence of `<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>`, and I've looked through the docs of np.concatenate(), it tells me that:[enter link description here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

> numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0, out=None)
>   Join a sequence of arrays along an existing axis.
>   Parameters: 
>   a1, a2, … : **sequence of array_like**
>   The arrays must have the same shape, except in the dimension corresponding to axis (the first, by default).

and I have tried some samples like：

```
x = Image.open('flows/v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c01/frame/img_00001.jpg').convert('RGB')
y = Image.open('flows/v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c01/frame/img_00002.jpg').convert('RGB')
z = np.concatenate([x,y], axis=2)
```

then it worked! the `z` is a `numpy.ndarray` type whose size is (240,320,6). However, the `<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>` seems not the kinds of `array` that the `np.concatenate()` parameters need, so I wonder how it works?

Comment: `concatenate` works with compatible lists (or nested lists).  I assume it's converting them to arrays before doing the concatenate (though the under-the-covers details may be different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the [`source` for `PIL.Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/Image.html#Image), you will see that it has a property called `__array_interface__` and the comment below it says:

*# numpy array interface support*.

My guess is that `numpy` is using this property to convert the image to an array and thus is able to manipulate it as one.

It is also this property that makes the `Image` object, "array_like". See [`__array_interface__`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html#__array_interface__).

Answer (score 1):

Numpy operates on [array-like](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html) objects. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/numpy-formal-definition-of-array-like-objects) to a question regarding what constitutes array-likeness. One way for a python object to be array-like is to implement the `__array_interface__` method. That is precisely what [`PIL.Image`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/3.1.x/PIL/Image.py#L618-L628) does.