# Is a set converted to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am creating a ndarray using:

```py
import numpy as np

arr=np.array({1,2})
print(arr, type(arr))
```

which outputs

```py
{1, 2} <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

If its type is numpy.ndarray, then o/p must be in square brackets like [1,2]?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's because you put on the function np.array a set and not a list
if you try this:

```py
import numpy as np

arr=np.array([1,2]) 
print(arr, type(arr))
```

you get:

```py
[1 2] <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns a numpy array object with no dimensions. A set is an object. It is similar to passing `numpy.array` a number (without brackets). See the difference here:

```
arr=np.array([1]) 
arr.shape: (1,)


arr=np.array(1) 
arr.shape: ()

arr=np.array({1,2}) 
arr.shape: ()
```

Therefore, it treats your entire set as a single object and creates a numpy array with no dimensions that only returns the set object. Sets are not `array-like` and do not have order, hence according to [numpy array doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) they are not converted to arrays like you expect. If you wish to create a numpy array from a set and you do not care about its order, use:

```
arr=np.fromiter({1,2},int)
arr.shape: (2,)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does something slightly different than you might imagine. Instead of constructing an array with the data you specify, the numbers 1 and 2, you're actually building an array of type `object`. See below:

```py
>>> np.array({1, 2)).dtype
dtype('O')
```

This is because sets are not "array-like", in NumPy's terminology, in particular they are not ordered. Thus the array construction does not build an array with the *contents* of the set, but with the set itself as a single object.

If you really want to build an array from the set's contents you could do the following:

```py
>>> x = np.fromiter(iter({1, 2}), dtype=int)
>>> x.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

Edit: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/numpy-formal-definition-of-array-like-objects) helps explain how various types are used to build an array in NumPy.

Answer (score 0):

The `repr` display of `ipython` may make this clearer:

```
In [162]: arr=np.array({1,2})                                                                          
In [163]: arr                                                                                          
Out[163]: array({1, 2}, dtype=object)
```

`arr` is a 0d array, object dtype, contain 1 item, the set.

But if we first turn the set into a list:

```
In [164]: arr=np.array(list({1,2}))                                                                    
In [165]: arr                                                                                          
Out[165]: array([1, 2])
```

now we have a 1d (2,) integer dtype array.

`np.array(...)` converts list (and list like) arguments into a multdimensional array.  A `set` is not sufficiently `list-like`.