# Why is this numpy array still a generator?

Tags: python, numpy, generator

This code is supposed to generate a vector field from data (*data*) which describes how often a cell is visited.

```
def vectorfield(maze, walk, data):
    # associate a zero vector with each location in walkable space
    tempdata = {pair:np.zeros(2) for pair in walk}

    for x, y in tempdata.keys():
        value = data[x][y] # how many times an agent visited this cell
        for dx, dy in itertools.product([-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1]):
            # if (x+dx, y+dy) is a neigbhor of (x, y) use its value for computation
            if dx or dy and (x+dx, y+dy) in walk:
                tempdata[(x, y)] += np.array([dx*value,dy*value])

    # largest length of corresponding vectors
    m = np.amax(np.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2) for vx, vy in tempdata.values())
    t = {key : value/m for key, value in tempdata.items()}
    tempdata = t

    x, y = tempdata.keys()
    u, v = tempdata.values()

    return x, y, u, v
```

The bit of code with `{key : value/m for key, value in tempdata.items()}` yields an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'generator'`. The division comes from the fact that I need to normalize each vector. Why is that error displayed?

Comment: dict values, keys, items are all generators.  `np.array` requires a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native Python `max`, and many other functions, take an *iterable* as their parameter, meaning an object that has either a `__getitem__` method or an `__iter__` method which returns an iterator ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884259/567595)). This includes lists, tuples and generators.

`numpy` functions such as `np.amax` take a different approach, usually accepting an ["array-like"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/numpy-formal-definition-of-array-like-objects) argument. Generally, these have `__getitem__` and also have a defined length. Generators do not have a defined length. If it gets something else, such as a generator, it treats it as a 0-dimensional array containing only that object. The maximum of such an array is simply the generator object it contains.

This is why `m` in your code is a generator rather than a number, and why `value/m` raises an error.

As already answered, you can get around this using a list comprehension. You could also use [`np.fromiter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367565/how-do-i-build-a-numpy-array-from-a-generator).

Answer (score 0):

```
(np.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2) for vx, vy in tempdata.values())
```

creates a generator expression. `np.amax` doesn't change the type, it just returns the max value. Try to make it a `list` instead

```
m = np.amax([np.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2) for vx, vy in tempdata.values()])
```