# Can I use numpy.ndarray and pandas.core.series as two inputs to sklearn accuracy_score?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

My `sklearn` `accuracy_score` function takes two following inputs:

```
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_class)
```

`y_test` is of `pandas.core.series` and `y_pred_class` is of `numpy.ndarray`. **So do two different inputs produce wrong accuracy?** It's actually giving no error and produce some score. **If my procedure is not correct what should I do to produce accuracy correctly?**

**Edit**

It's a binary classification problem and labels are not one-hot-encoded. So model.predict produces one probability value for each sample which are converted to label using np.round.

Outputs of `model.predict` looks like this--->

```
[[0.50104564]
 [0.50104564]
 [0.20969158]
 ...
 [0.5010457 ]
 [0.5010457 ]
 [0.5010457 ]]
```

My `y_pred_class` after rounding off looks like this--->

```
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 ...
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
```

And `y_test` which is pandas.series looks like this (as expected)--->

```
34793    1
60761    0
58442    0
56299    1
89501    0
        ..
91507    1
25467    1
79635    0
22230    1
22919    1
```

Are y_pred_class and y_test compatible to each other for accuracy_score() ?

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/9aaed4987/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py#L146) documentation says inputs shoud be `array-like` or `sparse matrix`. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/numpy-formal-definition-of-array-like-objects) an array-like is any Python object that np.array can convert to an ndarray so yes you could use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: Yes, you can.
Pandas is built upon numpy library.
A small test:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np

y_true = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1])
y_pred = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 0])
print(accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(y_true, np.array(y_pred)))
```

Comment: Plz look into the 'edit' portion in my original question once.

Comment: Yes, but always and always make sure inputs to have the same shape, so convert your predictions into 1d array using y_pred_class.squeeze()