# Why is it required to typecast a map into a list to assign it to a pandas series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have just started learning the basics of pandas, and there is one thing which made me think.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
data['Column2'] = map(str.lower, data['Column1'])
print(data)
```

The output for this program is:

```
   Column1                             Column2
 0       A  <map object at 0x00000205D80BCF98>
 1       B  <map object at 0x00000205D80BCF98>
 2       C  <map object at 0x00000205D80BCF98>
```

One possible solution to get the desired output is to typecast the map object into a list.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
data['Column2'] = list(map(str.lower, data['Column1']))
print(data)
```

Output:

```
   Column1 Column2
 0       A       a
 1       B       b
 2       C       c
```

However if I use range(), which also returns its own type in Python 3, there is no need to typecast the object to a list.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
data['Column2'] = range(3)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
   Column1  Column2
 0       A        0
 1       B        1
 2       C        2
```

Is there any reason why range object is not required to be typecasted but map object is?

Comment: can not reproduce first one

Comment: I'm able to reproduce both examples in 0.20.3

Comment: Maybe that's why Pandas has `data['Column1'].map(str.lower)`? I don't know the answer but maybe it has something to do with the built-in map being different from an array map?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer but you might be interested to find that `data['Column1'].map(str.lower)` gets you directly to the list-mapped result.  Which seems odd at first glance because [`Series.map`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/series.py#L2126) just applies `map` to the values.

Comment: @BradSolomon in this case - the OP should be using `data['Column1'].str.lower()` though...

Comment: @JonClements I agree that would be preferable.  Just bringing attention to difference between native `map` and `Series.map`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `range`s have `__getitem__`, and `__len__`, while `map`s don't.

---

#### The details

I'm assuming that the syntax of creating a new dataframe column is in some way syntactic sugar for [Pandas.DataFrame.insert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html), which takes as an argument for `value` a

> scalar, Series, or array-like

Given that, it seems the question reduces to "Why does pandas treat a list and a range as array-like, but not a map?"

See: [numpy: formal definition of "array_like" objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427/numpy-formal-definition-of-array-like-objects).

If you try making an array out of a range, it works fine, because range is close enough to array-like, but you can't do so with a map.

> >>> import numpy as np
>   
> >>> foo = np.array(range(10))
>   
> >>> bar = np.array(map(lambda x: x + 1, range(10))
>   
> >>> foo
>   
> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>   
> >>> bar
>   
> array(<map object at 0x7f7e553219e8>, dtype=object)

`map` is not "array-like", while `range` is.

Looking further into [PyArray_GetArrayParamsFromObject](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L1538), referred to in the linked answer, the end of the function calls PySequence_Check.  That code is python code, and there's a good discussion of it on Stack Overflow: [What is Python's sequence protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566044/what-is-pythons-sequence-protocol)
.

Earlier, in the [same file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L812), it says:

> ```
>    /*
>      * PySequence_Check detects whether an old type object is a
>      * sequence by the presence of the __getitem__ attribute, and
>      * for new type objects that aren't dictionaries by the
>      * presence of the __len__ attribute as well. In either case it
>      * is possible to have an object that tests as a sequence but
>      * doesn't behave as a sequence and consequently, the
>      * PySequence_GetItem call can fail. When that happens and the
>      * object looks like a dictionary, we truncate the dimensions
>      * and set the object creation flag, otherwise we pass the
>      * error back up the call chain.
>      */
> ```

This seems to be a major part of "array-like" - any item that has **getitem** and **len** is array like.  `range` has both, while `map` has neither.

#### Try it yourself!

`__getitem__` and `__len__` are necessary and sufficient to make a sequence, and therefore get the column to display as you wish instead of as a single object.

Try this:

```
class Column(object):
    def __len__(self):
        return 5
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < 5:
            return index+5
        else:
            raise IndexError

col = Column()
a_col = np.array(col)
```

- If you don't have either `__getitem__()` or `__len()__`, numpy will create an array for you, but it will be with the object in it, and it won't iterate through for you.
- If you have both functions, it displays the way you want.

(Thanks to user2357112 for correcting me.  In a slightly simpler example, I thought `__iter__` was required.  It's not.  The `__getitem__` function does need to make sure the index is in range, though.)

Comment: @Bharathshetty I rolled back your edit - it seems to me that OP is patently aware that adding a map produces only one element.  I felt your addition didn't help clarify why.

Comment: Also of interest: [Terminology: Python and Numpy - `iterable` versus `array_like`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216975/terminology-python-and-numpy-iterable-versus-array-like).  In this case, a `map` object _is_ iterable (as is `range`), but the former doesn't seem to be array-like, while the latter is.

Comment: `__len__` and `__getitem__` should be sufficient; the problem is that your `__getitem__` doesn't raise `IndexError` for out-of-range accesses.

Comment: Also, the comment in the code isn't quite right about PySequence_Check; PySequence_Check doesn't actually look for `__len__`. (I believe the part of the NumPy code that considers objects without a `__len__` to be non-sequences is actually the `PySequence_Length(obj) < 0` check earlier in the same function.)

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the details!  I've incorporated the IndexError into my answer.  I'm not sure what to do with your other statement.  If you want to leave it as a comment, that's fine.  If you prefer to edit it in yourself, you're welcome to.